# Set focus on disabled button programatically not working

Tags: jquery, html, button

```js
$(function () {
    $('#save').click(function() {
        $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        console.log($(document.activeElement).attr('id'));
    });
    $('#test').focus();
    console.log($(document.activeElement).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
button:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="body">
  <button id="discard" disabled="disabled">Discard</button>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
</body>
```

I have a `Discard Changes` button, and when clicked, the user sees a confirmation dialog that says "Are you sure you want to discard your changes?". When they click `OK`, we close the dialog and want to put focus back on the `Discard Changes` button, but we've disabled it now because there are no changes to discard. When I check the `document.activeElement` value, it's not the disabled button, it's the body element. However, when a user clicks the `Save` button, since they're physically setting focus on the element, it gets the focus so even after it's disabled, it has focus. For some reason in the snippet I'm not seeing my focus style set on the disabled Save button even though in my app I do see it.

Is it possible to set focus on a disabled button using jQuery? If not, why not? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Disabled specifically means it cannot be interacted with, and adding focus requires an interaction. I think you'd be better off changing the workflow instead of coding around it.

Comment: Focus isn't so much an interaction as indicating where the user is on the page, and the goal is to keep focus in a logical place especially for screen reader users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the button cannot receive focus because it is disabled.  According to the [W3.org specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled) (HTML5 version) disabled form controls must prevent click events and other interaction.

What you would need to do is enable the control at some point and assign focus that way.  Another suggestion would be to leave the button enabled and implement some form of detection to determine whether or not to respond to the discard button's `click` event.

Also, (and I'm taking a guess here) the save button likely shows as active because it was active before it was disabled.  Although the browsers need to prevent access to a disabled item though interaction, removing the focus (or `document.activeElement` in this case) may not be an implementation requirement of the specification.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to join the party late, but you can use `aria-disabled` attribute instead of `disabled`, and your element will be able to be assigned focus (even in IE and mobile, usually this problem doesn't rise in Chrome or Edge).

As a side note, if you also want your element to be navigable with keyboard TAB, of course make sure to set `tabindex="0"` (however this is not needed for programmatically assign focus via JavaScript).

Answer (score -2):

aria-disabled will allow focus() to disabled elements

Comment: How does this differ from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3733638/mlr) from [mlr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3733638/mlr): *you can use `aria-disabled` attribute instead of `disabled`, and your element will be able to be assigned focus*?

Comment: This answer was already stated and well explained.